# How to use rollapplyr while ignoring NA values?

Tags: r

I have weather data with NAs sporadically throughout and I want to calculate rolling means. I have been using the `rollapplyr` function within `zoo` but even though I include `partial = TRUE`, it still puts a NA whenever, for example, there is a NA in 1 of the 30 values to be averaged.

Here is the formula:

```
weather_rolled <- weather %>%
  mutate(maxt30 = rollapplyr(max_temp, 30, mean, partial = TRUE))
```

Here's my data:

## A tibble: 7,160 x 11

```
   station_name date       max_temp avg_temp min_temp rainfall    rh avg_wind_speed dew_point avg_bare_soil_temp total_solar_rad
   <chr>        <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>     <dbl>              <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-01      0.9     -7.9    -16.6      1    81.7          20.2      -7.67                 NA              NA
 2 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-02      5.5      1.5     -2.5      0    74.9          13.5      -1.57                 NA              NA
 3 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-03      3.3     -0.9     -5        0.5  80.6          10.1      -3.18                 NA              NA
 4 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-04     -1.1     -4.7     -8.2      5.2  92.1           8.67     -4.76                 NA              NA
 5 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-05     -3.8     -6.5     -9.2      0.2  92.6          14.3      -6.81                 NA              NA
 6 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-06     -3       -4.4     -5.9      0    91.1          16.2      -5.72                 NA              NA
 7 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-07     -5.8    -12.2    -18.5      0    75.5          30.6     -16.9                  NA              NA
 8 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-08    -17.4    -21.6    -25.7      1.2  67.8          16.1     -26.1                  NA              NA
 9 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-09    -12.9    -15.1    -17.4      0.2  71.5          14.3     -17.7                  NA              NA
10 VEGREVILLE   2019-01-10    -13.2    -17.9    -22.5      0.4  80.2           3.38    -21.8                  NA              NA
# ... with 7,150 more rows
```

Essentially, whenever a NA appears midway through, it results in a lot of NAs for the rolling mean. I want to still calculate the rolling mean within that time frame, ignoring the NAs. Does anyone know a way to get around this? I have been searching online for hours to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: `zoo::rollapplyr`, has the option of adding additional arguments to `FUN`.. i.e. can you add `na.rm=T` to the `rollapplyr()` call?

Comment: This did it! Thanks so much!